# go undefined functions in templ object

Tags: go

I'm using golang templ lib and I'm facing a weird error with this function

```
templ Show(user model.User) {
  @layout.Base() {
    <h1>hello {user.Email} from user page</h1>
  }
}
```

there was no problem before adding this `{user.Email}`

in the end of the text, vscode shows this

```
undefined: templ.JoinStringErrs compiler
undefined: templ.Error compiler
```

after executing `templ generate` it appears that both Error and JoinStringsError are undefined in go generated file

Comment: Do you can more explain about your problem ? because I tested a simple example but not get this error; show folder implantation, version templ, User Model and some more code if you can.

Comment: Well it's just what can u see from the snippet above, the templ version is the latest, even though I get that warning when I generate "invalid go version '1.21.5': must match format 1.23", the problem happened after I injected the user model struct trying to show it out

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal reproduction of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue with templ v0.2.476, updating it to the latest version (current v0.2.501) fixed it for me.